# What is considered "media" when referring to Facebook Pages autoplay policy?

Tags: facebook-pages

Facebook Pages policy states that *media auto-play* is not allowed on a Facebook Page. Now I wonder what is considered *media*? JavaScript with `setTimout`/`setInterval` as well?

If I put a jQuery carousel/slider/fader on my Page's custom tab that rotates some HTML text elements every 10 seconds and starts cycling the moment Facebook Page's loaded. **Is this regarded as *media*?** It's Javascript that rotates text so to me this is not media...

See it [here](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Pleiado-doo/239239426096812?sk=app_128953167177144) and tell me whether this can be considered media...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media generally refers to video and audio elements.  The auto play ban is in reference probably to when it was popular for people to throw audio and video clips on their site that played as soon as a user opened the page... which then and even more so now was considered to be bad design and bad for the user experience.

What you are describing doesn't fit into that situation so you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm glad I can leave it the way it's done now. Auto slider/fader starts immediately when page loads.

Comment: Just to follow on from what you were discussing - would an autoplaying swf file fall under the Facebook ban? Is it considered a 'video' element? Quite confused as to what exactly Facebook mean by 'media'... I wish they'd be more specific. What do you think? Here's the page anyway: http://www.facebook.com/BurrenInBloom?sk=app_190322544333196